# Select the value from an array of hashes based on key from a single document in mongoid

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I have a document in `items` collection like

```
// Document One
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("556411af73616d0d822f0000"),
    "visibility" : [
        {
            "user_id" : ObjectId("556412bb73616d0d82310000"),
            "visible" : false
        },
        {
            "user_id" : ObjectId("556412c973616d0d82320000"),
            "visible" : true
        }
    ]
},

// Some other documents
{...}
{...}
```

I want to get the value of `visible` only for "Document One" based on `user_id` I provide (eg. ObjectId("556412bb73616d0d82310000")).

How?

I am using mongoid 4.0.0.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in two ways :

1> Using `$elemMatch` and `$` in projection as below

```
db.collectionName.find({"visibility":{"$elemMatch":{"user_id":ObjectId("556412bb73616d0d82310000")}}},
{"visibility.$visible":1,"_id":0})
```

it retunrns results as

```
"visibility" : [ { "user_id" : ObjectId("556412bb73616d0d82310000"), "visible" : false } ]
```

this return whole matching array in `visibility`

2> Using `aggregation` as below :

```
 db.collectionName.aggregate({
   "$unwind": "$visibility"
 }, {
   "$match": {
     "visibility.user_id": ObjectId("556412bb73616d0d82310000")
   }
 }, {
   "$project": {
     "_id": 0,
     "visible": "$visibility.visible"
   }
 })
```

return results as `{ "visible" : false }`

Comment: In aggregate, is it possible to do without $unwind?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this:

```
db.one.find(
   {"visibility.user_id": ObjectId("556412bb73616d0d82310000")},
   {_id: 0, "visibility.$": 1})
```

In the query statements`db.collection.find(query, projection)`, `{"visibility.user_id": ObjectId("")}` is used to select the required item, and `{_id: 0, "visibility.$": 1}` is used to show the specified field.
    What's more, $ operator (projection) is used to limit the output to be the matched one of array.

Official Doc: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#projection

> $
>   The positional $ operator limits the contents of an  from the query results to contain only the first element matching the query document. To specify an array element to update, see the positional $ operator for updates.

Use $ in the projection document of the find() method or the findOne() method when you only need one particular array element in selected documents.